# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'liburdl.lib'

Tags: c++, boost

I'm making a function to download a file from internet, already installed Boost 1:55, added the urdl libraries already added the directories in VSC + + 2013 everything went right.

But now I came across this error saying it is missing this liburdl.lib already searched on google and found somewhere to download and the folder has no urdl. Lib

```
Error   9   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'liburdl.lib'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the urdl documentation, you need to build it first, see [Building and using Urdl](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/urdl/getting_started/building.html)

Comment: Created the environment variable >>> http://i.imgur.com/Tetl039.png But I did not understand this part >>> Run bjam in the top-level directory of the Urdl distribution. Libraries should be built into the lib subdirectory.

Comment: @JCássio Take a look at [these instructions for boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source). It includes instructions how to get bjam.